Looking for trace routing software compatible with kicad on ubuntu
Long ago I used kicad, and there was rudimentary tracerouting. Its been a minute, and that feature has evidently been removed. So Im looking for trace routing software comapable with kicad. I read about free routing, but when I try to install it... failure.
Is there a trace routing program that can help me optimize electrical traces on PCB layouts, for Ubuntu?
Im on Jammy Jellyfish.
Acceptable answers would be software that is for Ubuntu to optimize pcb trace lay out, or a detailed description of how to install freerouting on Ubuntu 22.04
Software in question:
https://github.com/freerouting/freerouting
